# Put all CustomControl styles into Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, controltemplate, winui-3

I have created several `CustomControl`s for using on my project. I have defined two projects:

1. A `ClassLibrary` which contains my `CustomControl`s.
2. A `WinUI` application which uses `ClassLibrary`.

In the `ClassLibrary` I have created a custom control named `Badge`; Automatically visual studio defined a default `Style` with a sample `Control Template` for this `Badge` in `Generic.xaml` file under `Themes` folder.

I defined several Styles for this control. And I just put them into a file named `BadgeStyle.xaml` so I added this file as a `MergedDictionary` in `Generic.xaml`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:customControls="using:BSN.Kava.UI.SDK.CustomControls">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///BSN.Kava.UI.SDK/CustomControls/BadgeStyle.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
    <Style TargetType="customControls:Badge" BasedOn="{StaticResource BadgeBase}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I hoped that I'm able to use these `Styles` in my main `WinUI3` application. But I can't. I should directly reference this `BadgeStyle.xaml` in `App.xaml` resource dictionary.

Surprisingly this line works (Without direct referencing to `BadgeStyle.xaml` in the `app.xaml`):

```xml
<Style TargetType="customControls:Badge" BasedOn="{StaticResource BadgeBase}" />
```

But the rest won't works.

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a control library project called **CustomControlsLibrary** and your WinUI 3 app project has a reference to that library project.

And in **CustomControlsLibrary**, you have a custom control **CustomItem**. Usually, you would have its template on:

**CustomControlsLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomItem">
                <Button
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Content="Default style" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You also have additional styles for **CustomItem** in a seperate file:

**CustomControlsLibrary/Themes/CustomItemStyles.xaml**

```xml
<Style
    x:Key="CustomItemSkyBlueStyle"
    TargetType="local:CustomItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomItem">
                <Button
                    Background="SkyBlue"
                    Content="SkyBlue style" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style
    x:Key="CustomItemLightGreenStyle"
    TargetType="local:CustomItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomItem">
                <Button
                    Background="LightGreen"
                    Content="LightGreen style" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In order to use the additional styles in you WinUI 3 app project, you need to declare it on App.xaml.

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="CustomControlStylesExample.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControlStylesExample">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!--  Other merged dictionaries here  -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomControlsLibrary/Themes/CustomItemStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  Other app resources here  -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then, you'll be able to use it:

```xml
<custom:CustomItem Style="{StaticResource CustomItemSkyBlueStyle}" />
<custom:CustomItem Style="{StaticResource CustomItemLightGreenStyle}" />
```

**UPDATE**

If you are placing your additional styles in **Generic.xaml**:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    <!--  Other merged dictionaries here  -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomControlsLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```